# VB6 string variable truncating data that it reads from a file

Tags: string, variables, vb6

When I am reading a 600kb text file (HTML code) into a string variable, it is truncating pretty much half of the content. Here is the code I have... where am I going wrong?

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim f As File
Dim fsoStream As TextStream
Dim strLine As String
Set f = fso.GetFile("C:\Users\Neanderthal\Desktop\MyProj\GMATClubLog.txt")
Set fsoStream = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
' Read the file line by line, printing the results to the Form
Do While Not fsoStream.AtEndOfStream
     strLine = fsoStream.ReadLine
     Debug.Print strLine
Loop
Len(strLine)

fsoStream.Close
Set fsoStream = Nothing
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Basically why I want to read the whole content of the text file is because I want to extract a repeating set of  data based on the search criteria . And this is the repeating code

```
<td class="topicsName" style="width:100%">
<a class="newestPostIcon" href="http:someURL.com"></a>
<a title="some text" href="http://I want to extract this link.html" ></a> 
</td>
```

Comment: You are reading each line into a string variable. Are you saying each line is truncated or it is only getting half way through the file

Comment: does it stop at a specific character in the file? does it always stop the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to read in a whole file into a string is the following:

```
Dim intFile As Integer
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
strFile = "c:\temp\file.txt"
intFile = FreeFile
Open strFile For Input As #intFile
  strData = Input(LOF(intFile), #intFile)
Close #intFile
```

If you want you can then split the data into an array of lines as follows:

```
Dim strLine() As String
strLine = Split(strData, vbCrLf)
```

And then loop through the array (for example to print each line on the form):

```
Dim lngIndex As Long
For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(strLine)
  Print strLine(lngIndex)
Next lngIndex
```